# When redirecting to another domain, to which domain will HSTS apply?

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect, https, http, hsts

Assuming the following, what domain will be HSTS'ed for the next year, **foo.com** or **bar.com**? RTFM (RFC6797) doesn't help much.

```
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: foo.com
[ ... ]
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
< Location: https://bar.com
```

Comment: Technically it depends on the header sent when contacting second website (bad obfuscation, you should have used the `.example` TLD instead): maybe the second website also use HSTS with the same headers. But in general MAximillian answer holds: the header protects the ongoing HTTP exchange so applies to the website you are connecting too, whatever happens after the connection (error, serving local page, proxying, redirecting, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HSTS will apply to `foo.com`. HSTS always applies to the server serving the response itself.

If you think about it, if it worked the other way then people could set HSTS on each other's sites, which would be a big mess.